# Path not printing string values

Tags: python, python-2.7

I recently found this really handy library for pdf conversion. I am trying to convert a ***pdf*** to string values. In order to parse the data and convert to a csv file. I want to automate this for future so I cannot use Tabula.

I am calling some modules in order to convert pdf to string.
The part for string conversion is not working. (`pdf2string.py`)
Here is part for the pdf conversion to string.

I get no error. Success. But, there is no output.

```
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.converter import HTMLConverter
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
from cStringIO import StringIO
import re
import csv
import sys

def convert_pdf_to_html(path):
    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
    retstr = StringIO()
    codec = 'utf-8'
    laparams = LAParams()
    device = HTMLConverter(rsrcmgr, retstr, codec=codec, laparams=laparams)
    fp = file(path, 'rb')
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
    password = ""
    maxpages = 0 #is for all
    caching = True
    pagenos=set()
    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fp, pagenos, maxpages=maxpages, password=password, caching=caching, check_extractable=True):
        interpreter.process_page(page)
    fp.close()
    device.close()
    str = retstr.getvalue()
    retstr.close()
    return str

    print str

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) == 2:
        path = sys.argv[1]
        convert_pdf_to_html(path)
```

This is my bash.

```
python pdf2string.py example.pdf
```

Script is `pdf2string.py` and path is `example.pdf`.

I am also new to high-level logic in python.

Comment: Explain more what is not working. Is there an error? Some output that doesn't look how you expect?

Comment: The modules converts the pdf file to html string values. This tells me in which format to parse the file. It is suppose to give me an html tag. I get no error. I actually get a successful completion with out the ouput. What I need is 'str' output. I am thinking that my path is set up wrong. I cannot find anything wrong in the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: you are returning before printing - remove `return str`, or remove `print str` and use the advice below.

You're not printing the output of convert_pdf_to_html(), or saving it somewhere.

```
print convert_pdf_to_html(path)
```

Comment: Yes I fixed that. Some how I pressed control CMD Z.  I kept the 'str' because it gets the string for html. printing the function still does not give html tag string I need. I know it's something small but can't seem to catch it. Appreciate it.